# PHP Helper Class to create shortcodes

Tags: php, shortcode, oop, fatal-error, customization

I created a helper class to extend other classes for shortcodes.

When I try to use `$this` in the `add_shortcode()` function I'm getting this error:

```
Using $this when not in object context
```

How can I solve this?

**Code below:**

Parent Class

```
//shortcode-helper.php
abstract class ShortcodeHelper {

    private $post_name_id;
    private $short_code_name;

    /**
     * ShortcodeHelper constructor.
     *
     * @param $post_name_id
     * @param $short_code_name
     */
    protected function __construct( $post_name_id, $short_code_name ) {
        $this->post_name_id      = $post_name_id;
        $this->short_code_name   = $short_code_name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets shortcode for the ShortcodeHelper
     */
    public function register() {
        add_shortcode( $this->short_code_name, $this->do_frontend_shortcode() );
    }

    protected function do_frontend_shortcode() {
        echo 'Test! '.$this->metabox_id;
    }
}
```

Child Class

```
//test-form.php
    class TestForm extends ShortcodeHelper {

        /**
         * TestForm constructor.
         */
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(
                //post_name_id
                'about_us',
                //short_code_name
                'cmb-about-form'
            );
        }
    }

    new TestForm();
```

Comment: What did you find when you searched for this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting class method you need to pass an array where **first argument is class instance** and **second is method name as string**.

Your `add_shortcode` line should look like this:

```
add_shortcode($this->short_code_name, array($this, 'do_frontend_shortcode'));
```